# Retrieving pixel array from image taken with a camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an app that needs to access an array of pixels from a picture after it is taken. The main Activity is below. I have a good amount of java experience but extremely limited experience with images past displaying them on the screen. I see the byte array being passed to the picture callback method but I do not know how it is formatted. How can I get a pixel array that includes the RGB components from the captured image? I tried to find this through the stack overflow forums however I got a few hundred pages of results and only searched through the first 10 or so, so I am sorry if that has already been asked and I just did not see it.

```
    public class ConverterActivity extends Activity 
{
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
private String TAG;
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
if (pictureFile == null){
// Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
//  e.getMessage());
return;
}
try {
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
fos.write(data);
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
captureButton.setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// get an image from the camera
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
}
}
);
        // Create an instance of Camera
        mCamera = Camera.open(this.getBackCamera());
        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mPreview);
}
@Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
    }
    private void releaseCamera(){
        if (mCamera != null){
            mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
// To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
// using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
// This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
// between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.
// Create the storage directory if it does not exist
if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
return null;
}
}
// Create a media file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File mediaFile;
if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
"IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
} else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
"VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
} else {
return null;
}
return mediaFile;
}
public int getBackCamera()
{
int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
CameraInfo cInfo = new CameraInfo();
for (int i = 0; i < numCameras; i++)
{
Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cInfo);
if (cInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
{
return i;
}
}
return -1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the picture using code like this:

```
    imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/somefolder/" + name + ".jpg");

    String fileName = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName)));

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Then you should be able to, when you get the result back from this intent, using code like this to access the bitmap

```
    if (imgFile.exists()) {
        String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap bm;

        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, opts);
        return bm;
    }
    else return null;
```

Then you can use  bitmapfactory tools, such as compress to stream and then
convert to byte[]

```
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);  // 100 = max quality
  byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a few questions though, I'm pretty unfamiliar with android and images. First what is that code replacing? just taking the picture and saving it? or is it replacing the Camera Preview as well? And how does the byte array represent the pixels? How would I retrieve the RGB components of a specific pixel using what you provided?

Comment: you have to set the component type using bitmapfactory as well.  options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 sets it to 2 and 3 pixels per component while ARGB_8888 sets it to 8 bits per pixel in each of alpha, red, green, blue.  I haven't tried, but I'd imagine you could index into this array of bytes on component and then x and y computed into single integer

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry to have to ask another question but would you mind clarifying what you mean in the last sentence? "I haven't tried, but I'd imagine you could index into this array of bytes on component and then x and y computed into single integer" I don't understand what you mean by indexing into the byte array on component or what you mean by "x and y computed into single integer"

Comment: byte[4*(y*rowsize+x)] would give you the alpha component of the xth pixel in the yth row.  If it were me, I'd create a picture with known colors and values and read that, making sure my indexing was correct and verify the color I read in was the color I expected to read at that location.

Comment: ok. thank you very much. i appreciate it. so to get the red component would that be byte[4*(rowsize+x)+1]?